# Rename substring of filename based on partial filename match in same folder

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, regex, .net-framework, vbscript

I have a folder full of files (.avi and .txt files):

```
'MyVideo1-MyEncode.avi'
'MyVideo1.avi 16-05-2019 15-41-01.txt'

'My Video 2.avi'
'My Video 2.avi 16-05-2019 16-43-11.txt'

'My Video 3 [Summer]-MyEncode.avi'
'My Video 3 [Summer].avi 16-05-2019 17-57-24.txt'

'My Video 4-(Fall).avi'
'My Video 4-(Fall).avi 13-05-2019 19-29-16.txt'

'My Video 5-(Winter)-MyEncode.avi'
'My Video 5-(Winter).avi 11-05-2019 11-15-05.txt'
```

If the .avi file includes **"-MyEncode"** in the filename, I would like to then copy this part of the string into the filename of the corresponding text file.

e.g.

**"MyVideo1-MyEncode.avi"** includes the text **"-MyEncode"** in the filename

so:
**"MyVideo1.avi 16-05-2019 15-41-01.txt"**

should be renamed as:
**"MyVideo1-MyEncode.avi 16-05-2019 15-41-01.txt"**

on the other hand:

**"My Video 2.avi"** *does not* contain the string "-MyEncode" so the corresponding .txt file should not be renamed.

I have a number of folders containing files like this.

I am thinking I need to run the cmd line or batch file for something like:

```
for /R %x in (*.avi) do ren "%x" *.txt
```

however this does not account for the partial filename match.

Can anyone please help?

PS - If I makes things easier, I can rename the like of "My Video 3 [Summer]-MyEncode.avi" to "My_Video_3_[Summer]-MyEncode.avi" (i.e. to remove the spaces)

Comment: Please, don't crosspost (https://stackoverflow.com/q/56174510/372239)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ended up being a hot-mess for me since the `-MyEncode` gets put in the middle of the file name, but this is what I came up with and it works based on the information you've provided:

```
@echo off

set "dir=C:\Your\Directory"
set "enc=-MyEncode"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /r "%dir%" %%A in ("*%enc%*.avi") do (
    set "sub=%%~nxA"
    set "name=!sub:~0,-13!"
    for /r "%dir%" %%B in ("*!name!*.txt") do (
        set "txt=%%~nxB"
        set "num=!txt:~-24!"
        set "fin=!name!!enc!.avi!num!"
        if not !txt!==!fin! ren "%dir%\!txt!" "!fin!"
    )
)
endlocal
```

For starters, `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` is required since we're dealing with variables used throughout our nested for-loop. These variables are used to make things a bit easier to digest and to change when you go back and edit, so up front I've set variables for both the directory in which the files are located (`dir`) and for the string you want to insert into your filenames (`enc`).

The initial for-loop checks the directory for all instances of .avi files that contain the string `-MyEncode`, and for each instance/iteration a parameter `%%A` is returned and used to `do` a few other commands. The first command in the initial loop sets a variable (`sub`) with the filename (`n`) and extension (`x`) of our `%%A` parameter - this cuts off all of the directory information since we won't need it. The second command uses our new `sub` variable to set a newer variable (`name`) that subtracts the last 13 characters from the filename (the last 13 being `-MyEncode.avi`) so we can use it for the next part: the nested for-loop.

Like the initial for-loop, our nested one looks in our directory - but instead of looking for .avi files containing our `enc` variable, it looks for .txt files containing our new `name` variable. The first command while setting the `txt` variable is to reduce `%%B` to its filename and extension, then we set a `num` variable that reduces the `txt` variable to its last 24 characters (the numbers and spaces at the end). Finally, it sets the variable `fin` to what we want the new text file to be called: `!name!!enc!.avi!num!` - this is the name established in the initial for-loop with `-MyEncode` added to it, a `.avi` added to that, then the numbers that were originally at the end. From here, we use an `if not` command to say that: for all `txt` variables that are not already equal to their `fin` counterparts, rename the `txt` to `fin`. I use `if not` here because the text files that have already been changed to reflect their corresponding .avi files don't need to be renamed again.

Hopefully this helps!